# What is this design called? (Cramming words into an area with some words bigger than others)

Tags: text, typography, font-design, style-identification

What is this design called? (Cramming words into an area with some words bigger than others) [image]

Are there tools to create this on the fly eg. Wordpress plugin. Picture is just an example I found on google.

Answer (score 5):

That's a "**Word Cloud**" (sometimes called a *word collage*, or - especially in Wordpress circles of old - a *tag cloud*) It's a visual representation of words that gives greater prominence to words that appear more frequently or are more important.

This visualisation can help presenters highlight the most common or important words in a way that everyone can understand.

For Wordpress in particular there are many [Tag Cloud plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/tag-cloud/). On Wordpress this is referred to as a "Tag Cloud" because it's used to show tags, and to highlight the more frequently used tags by making the font size larger.

Here's a cool Word Cloud generator you can play with. There are many others https://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud/

Comment: Word Clouds look like this, but I haven't heard that used when it's meant to be read as a sentence like in this specific example. No better term comes to mind though.

Comment: thank you for you reply. I have used word clouds before but in this particular instance I want it as a sentence. I was going to go with designing it myself but the client wants to change it every month.

Comment: I understand, but I still cannot think of a better term than "Word Cloud". I am sure you've tried to dissuade the client, because - as usual for clients - he is underestimating the job. It takes artistic skill to form a sentence as per your example.